# Versions of apc and php on mac

Tags: php, apc

I am trying to set up symfony2 project on my mac machine. I am using php 5.4.7.

When I start my webserver (apache 2.2.22) and go to site for a first time everything is good. But when I hit F5 (refresh) or when I go to some other link, I get error message "Server not found". When I hit F5 several time message I get is "Warning: require(): Unable to allocate memory for pool".

I guess it is related with APC. Version of APC I am using is 3.1.12

Does anyone know what can be a problem?

Comment: Sounds like APC is incorrectly configured.  You need to specify sensible limits in php.ini (or another ini file that gets included during startup).  However configuring APC is a bit of a black art so I can' really be more helpful than that I'm afraid.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have downgraded php to 5.3.17 and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a program like MAMP. As it is a complete tool with all the features you need, without having problems.

By the way, here is a possible solution: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-php-warning-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool/